# Filter for instances of classes in python

Tags: python, class, filter, instance

I'm making a plugin manager in python. My plan is to append all of my possible plugins (which could consist of classes, functions, and instances of classes) to a single list and then use custom filter functions to get out the appropriate objects.

How do you get all class instances out of a list? The class instances can be of any class.

example:

```
class A:
    pass

def func():
    pass

instance_a = A()

plugins = [func, A, instance_a]
```

Now how do I get only `instance_a` out of `plugins`, assuming that I don't have a reference to the class instance `A`? Is it even possible?

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to make sense to me. If you don't have a reference to the class, how would you know which class you're looking for in the list?

Comment: I want to return all instances, regardless of class.

Comment: All instances of _any_ class? Everything is an instance of some class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want all instances, which are not class definitions themselves and not functions, then you can achieve this with:

```
import types
[x for x in plugins if type(x) == types.InstanceType]
```

However, I would consider this really an error prone solution as really you just find anything that somehow extends `object` and does not have a special type for that, like functions do. It would be best to define a superclass for all plugins implemented via class instances and filter on that:

```
[x for x in plugins if isinstance(x, Plugin)]
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond! Might not have been clear enough, so I added in an example.

Comment: I thought it was obvious, but please see my updated answer where I apply what I have suggested to your particular case.

Comment: I was hoping there was a way to do it without holding onto a class reference, but looks like there's not.

Comment: I do not follow, please elaborate. The example code just demonstrates that what is returned is in fact what you expect to find there, it does not assume you know anything about the instances before you filter your list. But it will work that way only for those plugins which are class instances (will also work with superclasses), not for functions or class objects themselves. For class objects and functions there is no type/instance relation so the same sort of filtering would have little sense.

Comment: I would like to filter for everything that is a class instance without needing the class objects. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to accomplish this that I can think of, in case someone runs into a similar problem is:

```
class A:
    pass

def func():
    pass

 a = A()
 plugins = [a, A, func]

 instance_plugins = [x for x in plugins if inspect.isclass(type(x)) and not type(x) == type]
```

Comment: It makes me sad that you take my answer and post it as your own solution while the question is still being clarified. I just updated my original answer.

Comment: Sorry, was working on this last night. I believe your answer to be more correct than mine however and have marked it as the solution.

Comment: Thanks. I would still advise to introduce class hierarchy and be specific in filtering. Best of luck.